# Ubuntu Apache Redirect All Request to HTTPS except Jenkins

Tags: apache, ubuntu, jenkins

I am creating a configuring a Server using Ubuntu and Apache. Everything works fine except that when I use redirection of HTTP to HTTPS.

How can I write an exception case where every http request is redirected to HTTPS except when its for JENKINS.

JENKINS : http://www.example.com:8080/  <= SHould not be redirected to HTTPS
Normal Request :   http://www.example.com/ <= Should be redirected to HTTPS

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  SSLEngine On
 # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This is really a question for [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Your sample configuration looks almost correct. You can create a separate `VirtualHost` for port `8080`.

```
<Virtualhost *:8080>
ServerName example.com
.
.

ProxyPass / http://jenkins:8080/
.
.
</Virtualhost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
  SSLEngine On
 # etc...
</VirtualHost>
```